# Video Streaming Protocols Comparison

Tags: nginx, streaming, video-streaming, rtmp

I'm trying to figure out the best way to stream video and I'm stuck on choosing my technology stack. Eventually what I want is to stream video (for now it's strictly  h264 streaming) as efficient as possible.  I'm new to streaming video and am quite confused choosing the transport protocol. I want to implement a streaming service where the packet loss is favored over latency, what would be the best transport protocol I could use?

I've been working with RTMP and still can't get the latency less than 30sec for 720p via 50mbit wifi connection.  I couldn't find any performance comparisons between transport protocols so either I haven't been looking in the right places or no such comparison can be done without specifying the information about the data being transfered. In any case, could anyone shed some light on the issue?

I don't know if it makes any difference but I'm using NGINX-based media streaming server, and I'm open to any other suggestions for the media server.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

For low latency you could choose a protocol like RTP/RTSP which is intended for realtime. Now if you want to further reduce latency - turn off B-frames on your H.264 encoder.

WebRTC may be another option.

Answer (score 0):

**A)    RTMP**

Drawback:

1)  For CDN, It will be costly since it work without caching.

2)  From point of view of security, RTMP Encrypted is somewhat flawed, as it is prone to Man-in-the-Middle Attacks. RTMP toolkit - RTMPDump can be used easily to download RTMP streams.

3)  RTMP streams your video in chunks it never loads ahead of time and viewers on slow speed connections might experience a bit of buffering as they wait for the rest of the file to stream.

4)  You could use rtmp only with Flash plugin.

5)  RTMP works on port 1935 only (Blocked by most corporate).

**B)HLS (from Apple)Adaptive Streaming**

Can be used with live + stored video streaming

Drawback:
This is platform dependent(good for IOS only)

**C)    Progressive /Pseudo Streaming**

Download video in chunks before request.

Platform Independent.

Supports all video formats and served from http protocol.

Use pre trans-coded video to work with par with adaptive streaming.

**Nginx has support for all above methods, ngx_http_mp4_module